Watts-Strogatz model: no edge from $p = 0$ graph should exist in $p = 1$ graph?
I'm trying to implement the Watts-Strogatz model for small-world networks. My understanding is that the procedure is as follows:
1. Start with a Regular Graph:

Begin by creating a ring lattice where each node is connected to its nearest neighbors. Specifically, in a graph with $n$ nodes, each node is connected to $k$ nearest neighbors.

2. Rewire Edges:

For each edge in the ring lattice, rewire the edge with probability $p$.
Rewiring involves keeping the source node fixed and randomly choosing a new destination node.
Ensure that no self-loops or multiple edges are created during this process.

Here's my Python code:
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def adjacent_edges(nodes, halfk):
    n = len(nodes)
    for i, u in enumerate(nodes):
        for j in range(i+1, i+halfk+1):
            v = nodes[j % n]
            yield u, v

def make_ring_lattice(n, k):
    """
    n: number of nodes
    k: degree of each node
    """
    G = nx.Graph()
    nodes = range(n)
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    G.add_edges_from(adjacent_edges(nodes, k//2)) # assume k is even in this example
    return G

def flip(p):
    """Returns True with probability `p`."""
    return np.random.random() < p

def rewire(G, p):
    """Rewires each edge with probability `p`.
    G: Graph
    p: float
    """
    nodes = set(G)
    for u, v in G.edges():
        if flip(p):
            choices = nodes - {u} - set(G[u]) # self loops or multiple edges
            new_v = np.random.choice(list(choices))
            G.remove_edge(u, v)
            G.add_edge(u, new_v)

def make_ws_graph(n, k, p):
    """Makes a Watts-Strogatz graph.
    n: number of nodes
    k: degree of each node
    p: probability of rewiring an edge
    """
    ws = make_ring_lattice(n, k)
    rewire(ws, p)
    return ws

# Generate and draw graphs
ws_0 = make_ws_graph(10, 4, 0)
ws_1 = make_ws_graph(10, 4, 1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

plt.subplot(121)
nx.draw_circular(ws_0, node_color='C1', node_size=1000, with_labels=True)
plt.title("p = 0")

plt.subplot(122)
nx.draw_circular(ws_1, node_color='C1', node_size=1000, with_labels=True)
plt.title("p = 1")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

This code produces the following two graphs:

My understanding is that, when $p = 1$, all edges should be rewired, meaning no edge from the original graph ($p = 0$) should remain in the final graph ($p = 1$). However, comparing these two graphs, I can see that some edges (e.g., between nodes 3 and 4) exist in both graphs. Is my understanding correct that no edge from $p = 0$ should exist in $p = 1$? I'm trying to figure out whether I'm misunderstanding the theory or whether the implementation is incorrect.

EDIT
If my understanding of this is correct, then I think the source of the problem is in the implementation as follows:

The loop for u, v in G.edges(): iterates over the original set of edges.

G[u] always reflects the current state of the graph.

When an edge (a, b) is rewired early in the loop:

It's removed from both G[a] and G[b]
New connections are made


Later in the loop, when we reach (b, a) (which is the same edge in an undirected graph):

This edge no longer exists in the current graph state
But it's still in the iterator from G.edges()


At this point:

choices = nodes - {u} - set(G[u]) will not exclude the original v (in this case, a)
Because a is no longer connected to b in the current graph state


This means that when p=1, it's possible for some edges to be "rewired" back to their original configuration.


